# List of plots arranged in a particular layout in a multipage PDF not working

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra

Suppose that out of a loop I am getting a particular set of plots that I am saving in a list of plots like in my reproducible example.

```
plot_list = list()

for (i in 1:5){

dummy1 = ggplot(iris, aes(x = Petal.Length)) +
  geom_histogram()

dummy2 = ggplot(iris, aes(x = Petal.Length, color=Species)) +
  geom_boxplot()

dummy3 = ggplot(iris, aes(x = Petal.Length, y=Petal.Width, color=Species)) +
  geom_point()

plot_list[[length(plot_list)+1]] = list(dummy1,dummy2,dummy3) 

}
```

After the iteration, once I have the plot list ready, I want to create a single pdf page with a particular layout matrix passed into every page. Following different posts I´ve tried this code:

```
lay = rbind (c(1,1,2,2),
             c(1,1,3,3),
             c(1,1,3,3))


grDevices::cairo_pdf("plots.pdf", onefile = TRUE)
for (i in seq(length(plot_list))) {
  do.call('marrangeGrob',list(plot_list[[i]], layout_matrix=lay))  
}
dev.off()
```

Unfortunately it only returns a blank pdf with a single page. Any help is appreciated.

UPDATE: Very importantly, my example serves as a reproducible example but its structure cannot be modified. The reason it comes out of a for is because in my original code comes from a `foreach` so the answer requires to be compatible with the structure I am proposing.

Comment: Is the issue with Stefan's answer that the solution needs to be called in a loop instead of lapply?  In that case you could replace the lapply call in Stefan's answer with the broadly equivalent  `for (i in plot_list) wrap_plots(i, design = lay) %>% print` (after loading library magrittr).

Comment: are you just missing an explicit `grid::grid.draw` which is required for grid graphics in a loop?

Comment: @CPB your solution produces a blank pdf, which was my original problem.

Comment: The other solution, proposed by @user20650, delivers a pdf that is corrupted and can´t be opened.

Comment: For me all of the solutions give the expected pdf output (5 pages, non-blank, no errors) for the minimal reproducible example in the question.  The blank pages and corrupted pdfs could indicate multiple graphics devices are open at the same time.  You can see the active graphics devices by calling `.Devices`.

Comment: Thanks @CPB, also worked but the solution by user was the best to the requirements in my original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To plot `ggplot`'s or other grid graphics then an explicit print is required: use `grid::grid.draw` (see [FAQ 7.22](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-do-lattice_002ftrellis-graphics-not-work_003f)).

Additionally, using `marrangeGrob` can add an extra newpage; [this fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41813198/r-using-marrangegrob-to-make-pdf-results-in-blank-first-page) unfortunately has an empty page at the start but [this](https://github.com/baptiste/gridextra/issues/33) still works.
Or you could move the `marrangeGrob` outside of the `pdf` call ... if this fits with our workflow.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
library(grid)

# Baptiste's fix
# if your example in your question represents your real example then you 
# could use `arrangeGrob` and avoid some of the newpage tweaks
grid.draw.arrangelist <- function(x, ...) {
  for(ii in seq_along(x)){
    if(ii>1) grid.newpage() 
     grid.draw(x[[ii]])
}
}

# Output plot
grDevices::cairo_pdf("plots.pdf", onefile = TRUE)

for (i in seq_along(plot_list)) {
  
  p <- marrangeGrob(grobs=plot_list[[i]], 
                    layout_matrix=lay, 
                    top = quote(paste("page", i, "of", length(plot_list))))
  grid::grid.draw(p) # need to be explicitly drawn 
  
  if(i < length(plot_list)) grid.newpage() # so plots are not drawn over each other
}

dev.off()
```

Comment: This works, and the fix as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach using `lapply` instead of a `for` loop and `patchwork` to combine your plots:

```r
library(patchwork)
library(ggplot2)

plot_list <- lapply(
  1:5,
  \(x) {
    list(
      ggplot(iris, aes(x = Petal.Length)) +
        geom_histogram(),
      ggplot(iris, aes(x = Petal.Length, color = Species)) +
        geom_boxplot(),
      ggplot(iris, aes(x = Petal.Length, y = Petal.Width, color = Species)) +
        geom_point()
    )
  }
)

lay <-
"
1122
1133
1133
"

grDevices::cairo_pdf("plots.pdf", onefile = TRUE)
lapply(
  plot_list, patchwork::wrap_plots,
  design = lay
)
#> [[1]]
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
dev.off()
#> quartz_off_screen 
#>                 2
```

[image]

And a second option would be to use `grid.arrange`:

```
grDevices::cairo_pdf("plots.pdf", onefile = TRUE)
for (i in seq(length(plot_list))) {
  grid.arrange(plot_list[[i]], layout_matrix = lay)
}
dev.off()
```

Comment: Thanks stefan, unfortunately I added the for in the example because there are several manipulations happening in the data before the plot at every distinct iteration, and hence, I need to take it out of the ```plot_list```. In this case, and even if I love using ```apply``` family functions, I would need another alternative that uses the extract from the list approach. I will try reading about ```patchwork``` and see if I can get something with it.

Comment: The adaptation of this solution with @CPB addition also worked ```grDevices::cairo_pdf("plots.pdf", onefile = TRUE)
for (i in plot_list) wrap_plots(i, design = lay) %>% print``` although the other solution was more adjusted to the question requirements.